# Change time stamp to specific date keeping existing time

Tags: touch

I have about 100 .jpeg images that I would like to change the file time stamp for. I have seen many examples of using `touch` to modify the time stamp based on the number of days, hours, etc., but those do not work in my situation.

I have attempted to use `touch -d "-1969 days ago"` on one of the files, but the new time was way off -- Jul 10 2021 rather than May 25 2014.

Is there any way to change all file time stamps in a directory to a specific date (2014-05-25) while keeping the time portion (2:30 PM in the example below) of the date time stamp?

For example, 2009-01-02 02:30 PM change timestamp to 2014-05-25 2:30 PM.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `date` and `touch`, here GNU coreutils.

If I read you correctly you want a specific date and keep file time, as in HMS. Not set each file say 300 days prior to the current value.

You can create that time by combining the string `2014-05-25` with the extracted time from the files by using `date`, for example:

```
$ date +"2014-05-25 %T.%N" -r file.jpg
2014-05-25 18:06:28.277679656
```

Then combine by doing something like:

```
for f in *.jpg; do touch -d "$(date +"2014-05-25 %T.%N" -r "$f")" "$f"; done
```

***Note that this can mess with DST and timezone.***

An alternative might be to add `%z` at end of date string, or add `-u` to `date` options.

```
TZ=UTC0 touch -d "$(date -u +"2014-05-25 %T.%N" -r "$f")"
```

## Test

Test, test, test before action. Check with `ls --full-time`, echo instead of touch etc. `find ... -printf` also have time/date options.

You could even do a backup of times to a text file.

---

## Notes:

From Q:

- 1969 days ago is 29 Sep 2010.
- 1969 days into the future is Jul 11 2021 (at least in my time zone).
- To get May 25 2014 from `"-1969 days ago"` current date has to be 15 Oct 2019.

The issue with `"-1969 days ago"` is that you have a minus in front of the time.

Minus + minus = plus

Either remove the minus sign, or remove the  *`ago`* part.

`1969 days ago` is 29 Sep 2010, as is `-1969 days`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and helpful comments. `for f in *.jpg; do TZ=UTC0 touch -d "$(date -u +"2014-05-25 %T.%N" -r "$f")" "$f"; done`worked perfectly for me.